# Installing Angular on Mac M1

Tags: macos, installation, angular-cli

I am having issues installing Angular I have a picture of my logs below.
I went to Nodejs.org installed newest version and It stays at version 16.8.0
I am not sure if this is an issue with Mac M1

Node version 16.8.0
Npm version 8.3.0
OS is macOS Big Sur versions 11.3.1

below is a link to my log messages of me trying to install Angular

[Log Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csKah.jpg)

any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your node is not required updates. Angular `13.1.2` need `16.10.0` and your node version is `v16.8.0`. Update your node first with the below command

```
brew update
brew upgrade node
```